# How to evalute a coefficient to a squared term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a very simple question, but one that still confuses me because I have never gotten a straight answer yet. I'm sure many of you already know the answer, but I have researched and looked online with no luck.

Say I have the following expression: $ 4(x+5)^2 $

This would be simplified into $ 4(x+5)(x+5) $

Would that then become $ (4x+20)(4x+20) $ or $ (4x+20)(4x+5) $ or something entirely different?

Basically, would the four distribute into both terms or just one of them?
Again, sorry for the super simple question, but it's a gap in my knowledge that I want to fill right now.

Comment: $a\cdot b\cdot c = (a\cdot b)\cdot c = a\cdot (b\cdot c)$.  This is true regardless of how simple or complicated $a,b,c$ happen to be.  In your case $4(x+5)^2=4\cdot (x+5)^2 = 4\cdot (x+5)\cdot (x+5)=\dots$.  Do not confuse it for $(4(x+5))^2$ which does simplify as $(4(x+5))^2=((4x+20))^2=(4x+20)\cdot(4x+20)$.

Answer (score 0):

$4(x+5)(x+5)$ means $(4(x+5))(x+5)$. So it becomes $(4x+20)(x+5)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$4(x+5)^2=4(x+5)(x+5)=4(x^2+10x+25)=4x^2+40x+100$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to check out which is right is to see what works for some convenient non-trivial value of $x$ (we want to avoid special cases). An identity is true for every value of $x$, and two different quadratic expressions (ie ones which don't take identical values) can agree for at most two different values of $x$. This is because a quadratic has at most two roots.

Here try $x=5$

We have $4(x+5)^2=4\times 10^2=400$

$(4x+20)(4x+20)=40\times 40=1600$, which is clearly wrong while $(4x+20)(x+5)$ comes out correct. So your second option is a candidate for the correct one, and you can see that the first one has acquired an extra factor of $4$, so it helps diagnose what has gone wrong.

Key points: use an easy value of $x$. Don't rely on this alone, but do use it to check your arithmetic and algebraic manipulation. If it is going to be complicated, then there is probably some easier way to check.

Answer (score 0):

When computing the product $4\cdot3\cdot3$, would you “distribute” the $4$ over both of the $3$s, obtaining $(4\cdot3)\cdot(4\cdot3)$? It’s no different when the terms in the product are polynomials instead of numbers.